# Creating Setup & Deployment of C# winApp in Visual Studio 2010 with Prerequisites

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, setup-deployment

I developed a windows forms application in C# win forms with crystal reports and sql server 2008 database.When i am trying to create setup exe of my application i need some prerequisites to deploy or install this application on client side i.e

List of Prerequisites

1. .NET Framework 4.0
2. SQL Server Express
3. Crystal Reports
4. Windows Installer

I take a new project from solution Explore>new project>other>setup and deployment>visual studio installer> after doing all this i go to prerequisite dialog box and check the above 4 items in list and mark "Download prerequisites from my application folder option"

but when i try to buid this setup i got these errors

1. General Failure Building Bootstrapper.
2. To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_10.msi' for item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.
3. Unrecoverable build error

Please solve this issue .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you place the prerequisite files in application folder.

Comment: @MohdWaseem yes i added a folder which contains crystal reports runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a full redistributable setup and Deployment package just follow the following steps:

If you are using VS2010 :

1. Add Setup and Deployment Project from Solution Explorer by right click and add new project>other project types>setup and Deployment>visual studio installer.
2. On application folder right click and add project output.
3. Now right click on the set up project a new dialog box appears for choosing prerequisites.
4. Now check the prerequisites from the list which you want i.e .Net framework 4.0,SAP crystal Reports for .NET,SQL Express etc.
5. You find all prerequisites in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages folder

> Sometimes crystal reports runtime not available as you mention in your error so i provide you a link to download these files

- [Crystal reports runtime for 32 bit](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_10.msi)
- [Crsytal Reports runtime for 64 bit](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_10.msi)

After downloading copy these files into Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal ....folder.

Now Try to Buid you setup.

I hope it will works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i download these two files and now all error was removed.Thanks for explaining .

Answer (score 0):

you need to place all youre prerequisites in the Microsoft sdk folder.
C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\......
or
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\......

It could be on a other location but just look for the bootstrapper\Packages folder in Microsoft sdk

If this dos not work! you could try InstallShield-Limited-Edition:
Go here and download it for free http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio register and get the key . its free :)

Comment: But there is no such folder exists only Microsoft SDK exists.So i have to create these folders.

Comment: Maybe try InstallShield-Limited-Edition if this dos not work.The link is in my answer.